Docker Vite tsx container Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html"
Vite React tsx app run fine in my local using nginx web server with Docker container. But when I run the app in Digital Ocean K8s cluster with nginx ingress controller. I am getting following error.
index-IS_bIaLF.js:1 Failed to load module script: Expected a JavaScript module script but the server responded with a MIME type of "text/html". Strict MIME type checking is enforced for module scripts per HTML spec.
my nginx.conf file:
worker_processes 4;

events { 
        worker_connections 1024; 
    
    }

http {
    server {
        listen 4173;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-test;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            
            # root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
    }
}

Docker file: 
# stage1 as builder
FROM node:21-alpine as builder

WORKDIR /app

# Copy the package.json and install dependencies
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

# Copy rest of the files
COPY . .

# Build the project
RUN npm run build


FROM nginx:alpine as production-build

COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

## Remove default nginx index page
RUN rm -rf /usr/share/nginx/html/*

# Copy from the stage 1
COPY --from=builder /app/dist /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-test

EXPOSE 4173


WORKDIR /usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-test

COPY ./env.sh .

# Expose port 4173 for the Nginx server
EXPOSE 4173

# Add bash
RUN apk add --no-cache bash

# Make our shell script executable
RUN chmod +x env.sh

# Start Nginx server
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/usr/share/nginx/html/nginx-test/env.sh && nginx -g \"daemon off;\""]

It runs fine in my Local. but in Cloud only I am getting Black White page.
K8s ingress.
kind: Ingress
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: test124
  namespace: test
  labels:
    app: ggg
  annotations:
    cert-manager.io/issuer: letsencrypt-nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - ragon.com
      secretName: letsencrypt-nginx
  rules:
    - host: ragon.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: service
                port:
                  number: 80

index.html file:
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <link rel="icon" type="image/svg+xml" href="./vite.svg" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Vite + React + TS</title>
    <script type="module" crossorigin src="./assets/index-IS_bIaLF.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" crossorigin href="./assets/index-DiwrgTda.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
  </body>
</html>

